# Convert array of objects to object using jq

Tags: arrays, parsing, jq

I am looking for way to convert array of objects as mentioned in example below to just an object using `jq`.

```
{
    "appName": "ABC",
    "target": [{
            "connectedApp_SalesforceServiceCloud": "false"
        },
        {
            "connectedApp_SalesforceSalesCloud": "false"
        },
        {
            "connectedApp_DataDotcom": "true"
        },
        {
            "connectedApp_SalesforceChatter": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

O/p Expected :

```
{
    "appName": "ABC",
    "target": {
        "connectedApp_SalesforceServiceCloud": "false",
        "connectedApp_SalesforceSalesCloud": "true",
        "connectedApp_DataDotcom": "true",
        "connectedApp_SalesforceChatter": "true"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just `add` the array of objects together. Use the `|=` operator to write it back to `.target` itself

```
jq '.target |= add'
```